# Displaying the name of tomorrow (ie. Monday)

Tags: javascript, php, date

Is there a simple way to display the name of the day of the week of tomorrow?

So far I have been able to do this in PHP (See below) and for today in Javascript but I am having trouble with tomorrow?

**Javascript for Today**

```
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var today = new Date();
document.write(days[today.getDay()]);
```

**PHP Version**

```
echo date("l", strtotime("+1 days"))
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

*I have seen a lot of stack overflow questions about this but they all seem very unreliable and complicated!*

Comment: You have two answers in your own question. What's your actual problem?

Comment: @elclanrs Exactly - Is this easy to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript seems fine, except that you are only printing today's day.

What you want to do is:

```
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var today = new Date().getDay();

document.write(days[(today + 1) % 7]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use use data time class

```
$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');
echo $tomorrow->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: OP wants it in JS, he already managed to do it in PHP